# Upload File Magento 2

Tags: image-upload, file-upload

there I'm trying to create a file upload attribute for a product this is what I have so far.

InstallSchema.php

```
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'my_attribute_image',
        [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'backend' => 'Vender\module\Model\Attribute\Product\Image',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'My Attribute Image',
        'input' => 'image',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'group' =>'My custom group',
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => 0,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

Model\Attribute\Product\Image.php

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Image extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
{

protected $_uploaderFactory;
protected $_filesystem;
protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
protected $_logger;
protected $httpFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\FileTransferFactory $httpFactory
    ) {
    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
    $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
    $this->httpFactory = $httpFactory;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}

public function afterSave($object)
{

    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    $image_name = $_FILES["product"]["name"]["my_attribute_image"];
    $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('ProductAttributes');

    // add image name as attbute value
    $object->setData($attributeCode , $image_name);
    $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $attributeCode);

    try {
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $image_name]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $result = $uploader->save($path);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() != \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader::TMP_NAME_EMPTY) {
            $this->_logger->critical($e);
            echo "ERROR";
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "</pre>";

}

}
```

$attributeCode is returning the correct value

$image_name is returning the correct value

$path is not including the domain name but is from home/public_html/pub/media...

The image name is correctly stored in the database in catalog_product_entity_varchar

But the image doesn't save in the folder or anywhere I can see.
No errors are thrown if i select an image but if i leave it empty error is echo

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have a Workaround using PHP 5 file upload this is my current solution

```
public function afterSave($object)
{
    $error = $_FILES["product"]["error"]["my_attribute_image"];

    if ($error == 4) {

    }else{

        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        $image_name = $_FILES["product"]["name"]["my_attribute_image"];
        $image_temp = $_FILES["product"]["tmp_name"]["my_attribute_image"];
        $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('ProductAttributes/');
        $extension_array = explode('.', $_FILES["product"]["name"]["my_attribute_image"]);
        $file_ext = end($extension_array);

        $object->setData($attributeCode , $image_name);
        $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $attributeCode);

        $alowed_extension= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

        if(in_array($file_ext,$alowed_extension)=== false){
            echo "extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
        }else{
            move_uploaded_file($image_temp,$path.$image_name);
        }

    }
}
```